# Is there a way to create a Service Fabric service and pass a docker command parameters to the container

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric

I am using Microsoft Service Fabric to orchestrate my docker containers and I have a Service Fabric service type that runs a docker image. I want to be able to pass command parameters to the container when it starts up.  I am hoping to launch 1 to n instances of the containers via CreateServiceAsync passing different parameters each time. 
 I am trying use the FabricClient.ServiceManagementClient.CreateServiceAsync method to launch each instance and hand those arguments to the docker container to receive as commmand parameters but I am at a loss of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, maybe you can create a special `ConfigurationService`, that can keep track of the function that the worker-services are performing.

At startup a worker-service would ask for configuration, and start doing that work. Periodically it will need to update a lease to indicate it's still alive.

This approach will allow any worker-service instance to perform any task, and ensure that hanging services are replaced with healthy ones.